# CGI Script in Python to search a database and print the results

Tags: python, cgi, urllib

I would like to write a CGI script that takes the form data, sends it to a search engine, searches, then displays the results on the webpage where my cgi script it run. I have been trying to use urllib and urllib2.

In my script: hello.py

```
if form.has_key("data_search"):
    datasearch = form["data_search"].value

    url = 'http://www.example.com/'

    data = urlparse.urlparse(datasearch)
    data2 = urllib.urlencode(data)


    req = urllib2.Request(url, data2)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data2)
    the_page = response.read()

    print response
    response.close()
```

So I would like to take the user input (datasearch), send it to a search engine at a different url (www.example.com), and print the results of the search on my webpage (www.server.com/cgi-bin/hello.py).

This current script is not working. I am not sure I have just made some sort of syntax error or if I need a new approach entirely.

The first error is in

data2 = urllib.urlencode(data)

builtin TypeError = 
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object 
      args = ('not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object',)

where the result of 'print data' is ('', '', 'TTBar', '', '', '')  and TTBar is my query.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the question?

Comment: Is the question clearer now that I have edited?

Comment: Where are things going wrong? Please print any stack traces you receive (and if you're just getting HTTP 500 errors, go through and add some print statements to see how far you're getting / what some of the values are).

Comment: What does 'is not working' mean, exactly? Do you get an error or just a blank page?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are getting your form data, but it appears that `datasearch = form["data_search"].value` returns the value of your `data_search` param already. Use `urlparse.urlparse` to parse a full url, i.e., http://somesite.com/?datasearch=TTBAR. So with that in mind you can do this:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://example.com'
datasearch = 'TTBAR'
req = urllib2.Request(url, {'param': datasearch})
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Or even better use the excellent [requests](http://python-requests.org) library:

```
resp = requests.post(url, {'param': datasearch})
```